# Weird vertical scroll and word breaks in ios9 when using open sans google fonts

Tags: css, web, ios9, google-font-api

I'm using Hebrew open sans google fonts in my [wordpress site](http://www.sciam.co.il/%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%93-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%90-%D7%90%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA/).
Only In ios9 (in all browsers - safari, chrome opera mini, and firefox) for an unknown reason there are strange word breaks: 
Sometimes there are long lines that go beyond the content width, which cause horizontal scroll; and sometimes one word will split into 3 lines.
[image: word split]

[image: long lines]